# RoR 5 find_or_initialize_by in nested form on has_many relationship not saving

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, nested-forms, ruby-on-rails-5, has-many-through

I have a feeling I'm missing something obvious...

The Usergrant records aren't saving or updating through the form (User#update).

Many Users can be associated with many Grants through the join table Usergrants

```
    class User < ActiveRecord::Base
      has_many :usergrants
      has_many :grants, through: :usergrants
      accepts_nested_attributes_for :usergrants, allow_destroy: true


    class Grant < ApplicationRecord
      validates_presence_of :name
      has_many :usergrants
      has_many :users, through: :usergrants
    end


    class Usergrant < ApplicationRecord
      belongs_to :user
      belongs_to :grant
      validates :user_id, :grant_id, :active, :percent, presence: true
    end
```

The controller (has Strong params):

```
def edit
  @title = "Edit User"

  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  @grants = Grant.all.where(active: true)

  if current_user == @user
    @page_title = "Edit your profile"
  else
    @page_title = "Edit "+@user.fname+"\'s profile"
  end

  if current_user.can_approve_this?(@user)
    @disabled = false
    @readonly_shower = "readonly-shower"
  else
    @disabled = true
    @readonly_shower = ""
  end

  @active_def = @user.active
  @salary_def = @user.pay_type
  @super_array = super_array
  @dept_array = dept_array
  @pw_lang = "Change password"
  session[:return_url] = back_uri

  if @user.pay_type == "Salary"
    @salary_hider = ""
    @hourly_hider = "hidden"
  else
    @salary_hider = "hidden"
    @hourly_hider = ""
  end
end

def update
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  @grants = Grant.all.where(active: true)

  @user.salary_rate == 0.0 if @user.salary_rate.nil?
  @user.hourly_rate == 0.0 if @user.hourly_rate.nil?

  if @user.update_attributes(user_params)
    flash[:success] = "Profile updated"
    redirect_to session[:return_url]
  else
    @dept_array = dept_array
    @super_array = super_array
    render 'edit'
  end
end

def user_params
  params.require(:user).permit(
    :id, :fname, :lname, :active,
    ...
    :usergrants_attributes => [:id, :user_id, :grant_id, :active, :percent])
end
```

And the user form:

```
<%= form_for( @user, remote: true) do |f| %>
...
  <% @grants.each do |grant| %>
    <%= f.fields_for :usergrant, @user.usergrants.find_or_initialize_by(user: @user, grant: grant) do |ug| %>
    ...
      <%= grant.name %>
      <%= ug.text_field :user_id, value: user.id %>
      <%= ug.text_field :grant_id, value: grant.id %>
      <%= ug.text_field :active %>
      <%= ug.text_field :percent %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
...
<% end %>
```

I can create Usergrant records in the console and they show up as expected in the form. And `User.usergrant` and `Grant.usergrant` are performing as expected.

Here's the log:

```
    Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"...", "user"=>{"id"=>"1", 
"fname"=>"Chip", "lname"=>"...", "email"=>"...", "time_zone"=>"Eastern Time (US & 
Canada)", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]", 
"usergrants_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"id"=>"2", "user_id"=>"1", "grant_id"=>"1", "active"=>"0", 
"percent"=>"0.0"}, "1"=>{"id"=>"1", "user_id"=>"1", "grant_id"=>"4", "active"=>"1", 
"percent"=>"25.0"}, "2"=>{"id"=>"3", "user_id"=>"1", "grant_id"=>"5", "active"=>"0", 
"percent"=>"0.0"}}}, "id"=>"1"}
```

What's my flaw?

Comment: Have you checked the parameters been sent matches the parameter structure the way it receives actually?!

Comment: Log results added to post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright, with the help of @Arslan_Ali and @crazy_vine, I was able to conquer this.

First, I was missing the `accepts_nested_attributes_for` call.

Second, I had to pluralize `<%= f.fields_for :usergrants  %>`

Third, I realized I could simplify this: `<%= f.fields_for :usergrant, @user.usergrants.find_or_initialize_by(grant: grant) do |ug| %>` (got rid of `user: @user`)

Fourth, I had to permit the User.id in the `users_params`, not sure why but the log told me ID was getting rejected in connection with my join table.

Fifth, I had form errors that I couldn't see because my top form was set to `remote: true`, removing this revealed that `Usergrant.active` and `Usergrant.percent` were throwing errors. I adjusted my validations and added defaults to my columns.

Stuff is working like gang busters now. Thanks for the wise guidance, folks!

Comment: In another 4 hours according to SO.

Answer (score 1):

Since a user has many `UserAgent` objects, so you need to write `accepts_nested_attributes_for` in `User` model:

```
accepts_nested_attriubtes_for :user_agents
```

Only then, you would be able to create or modify existing `UserAgent` objects for a given user.

**Edit:**

The other thing that you are doing is: `<%= f.fields_for :usergrant`. Since a `User` model has many Usergrants, so it must must be plural here like following:

```
<%= f.fields_for :usergrants  %>
```

Comment: so you're right that I was missing this (note the model is called Usergrants, long story), but the form is still not capturing the "initialized" records of Usergrants.

Comment: Done. I'm seeing issues with validations that I'm working on now, might be that simple (I had to take `remote: true` off the form to see the errors).